# How to start SQL Server 2008 automatically on Windows 7 startup?

Tags: sql-server-2008, mode

This question is not as simple as it seems to be. I have 64 bit SQL Server 2008 installed on a Windows 7 computer and it works fine when its running.

In the SQL Server Configuration Manager application (also seen in the Windows 7 Services window), the SQL Server instance `Start Mode` (`StartupType` in the Windows 7 Services window) is set to `Automatic`.

The problem that I have is that despite being set to `Automatic`, the SQL Server rarely starts automatically. I say 'rarely' because it does start sometimes.

At first I thought something must be wrong with the setting, so I set it to `Manual` and then back to `Automatic` and this seemed to work for a few days, but that may well have been a coincidence. Then I thought that there might be an error logged in the Windows 7 Event Viewer but there are no SQL Server entries until I manually start it.

Does anyone have any ideas what might be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that something MSSQL requires is not ready when it tries to load up.  This can happen for a variety of reasons such as dependency on network drives, or start-up security accounts, or a number of other reasons.

Try setting the startup mode from Automatic to Automatic (Delayed).

Take a look at this post over on dba.stackexchange.com for a similar issue with a full blown server running on a SAN and a variety of approaches to work around the issue.

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4936/how-to-delay-sql-server-startup

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Strangely, the SQL Server Configuration Manager application does not offer an `Automatic (Delayed)` option. I'll try that setting in the Windows 7 Services window instead and get back to you.

Comment: Well after changing the `StartupType` setting to `Automatic (Delayed)` yesterday, the SQL Server did start automatically today, but then it also started yesterday on the `Automatic` setting. I think it's a bit early to mark your answer as correct, so I'll come back in a few days after a few more start-ups. So far so good though. :-)

Comment: No problem :) - wish I had more to offer but hopefully that works for you.

Comment: Well the server has started everytime since changing the setting, so I can now set this as the correct answer. Thanks again.